# PHPBB - How to logout all users?

Tags: phpbb, phpbb3

How would I, as the administrator of the website, log out all users from PHPBB?
A custom PHP script, or is there a function in phpbb itself?

Would killing/removing the sessions from DB be enough?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In your ACP under the `General` tab there is an option to `Purge all sessions` - hit the `Run now` button and this will clear all sessions from the database thus logging everyone out.